# Finder does not recognize + in filename

Tags: finder

I use + signs in filenames to indicate quality of publications, e.g. Johnson 2013 +++.pdf. However, Finder gives me zero hits when I search for + either in filenames or file contents. I started using + in filenames under Windows, and I had not expected this error when I converted to Mac.

> I have no problem with other symbols e.g. ^, = or '. Also, I could replace or insert + in filenames with Automator without problem. But Finder does not even recognize a file named +.txt even when the + was inserted by Automator.

Any suggestions? I run OS X 10.7.5 (11G63) on a mid-2011 Macbook Air.

Answer (score 2):

If your just searching for + then put that in quotes like this "+" and finder should return results.